# Thinking in matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let's take a simple example. I am trying to change my way of thinking to get more matrix oriented.

I have data

```
epsilonM = [0.001 10*h h 0];
situations = ['i.a)' 'i.a)' 'i.Q' 'ii.:w']; 
hleg = legend(sprintf('%s Epsilon = %d, \n', situations, epsilonM));
```

I would like to get output

> i.a) Epsilon = 0.001
> i.a) Epsilon = 10*h,
> i.Q Epsilon = h,
> i.b) Epsilon = 0,

but I get

[image]

I have an intuition that there is a better way to do this - component wise.

**How can you achieve the result without use of for loops, only by matrices?**

Comment: For a 4 line string manipulation, I would use a loop. Your output is all garbled it's printing the 4 elements of `situations`, then the next part of your string `"Epsilon = "`, then the 4 elements of `epsilonM`. This behavior of `s/fprintf` is expected, but I've never found a good use for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's easier with cell arrays:

```
situations = {'i.a)' 'i.a)' 'i.Q' 'i.b)'};
epsilonM = {'0.001' '10*h' 'h' '0'};
aux = strcat(situations, {' Epsilon = '}, epsilonM);
legend(aux);
```

Note that the curly braces in `{' Epsilon = '}` are only necessary to prevent `strcat` from removing trailing white space (see [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) of `strcat`)

Comment: I use also **epsilonM** as data source. Is there any possibility of change int2str() there somehow? Or should I have two vars?

Comment: @Masi You probably need two vars. You could do `num2str` on your numeric variable `epsilonM`,  but you would get the numbers converted to strings, never an `h` as part of the strings

Comment: @Masi Now that I think about it: you could divide your numeric vector `epsilonM` by `h`. So `strcat(num2str(epsilonM(:)/h),'h')` could generate the desired string representation of `epsilonM`. Note that the `(:)` is necessary to turn `epsilonM`into a column vector, as `num2str` gives one result per row. Finally, use this to concat everything: `strcat(situations.', {' Epsilon = '}, strcat(num2str(epsilonM(:)/h),'h'))`

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of this line:

`situations = ['i.a)' 'i.a)' 'i.Q' 'ii.:w'];`

This is a single char of size 1 16, not the array you intended. I would recommend to use a cell:

`situations = {'i.a)' 'i.a)' 'i.Q' 'ii.:w'};`.

Thus:

```
epsilonM = [0.001 10*h h 0];
situations = {'i.a)' 'i.a)' 'i.Q' 'ii.:w'}; 
hleg = legend(sprintf('%s Epsilon = %d, \n', situations{:}, epsilonM));
```